# Lead on Corpus of Geographic Locations?

Tags: data-request, geospatial

Not sure if this should go here or in the GIS stack exchange, but I was wondering if anyone has a lead on a corpus of geographic locations? City names and coordinate pairs would be ideal, but I'll take whatever. I'm training a chatbot and I'd (ideally) like it to be able to pick up on locations in the chat and then display a map if requested.  Wishes and wants aside, if y'all do know of one or how I could make one, I'd appreciate it.

Thanks